# Display images twice in a node with different image cache settings

Tags: 7, nodes, entities, media

I have a node type where I'd like to display images as both thumbnails and full size images, so I'd like to use different image cache settings on the two image types. I don't want to use views to do this. I know that I can output a field twice using "print render($content['field_name']); " in my node.tpl file, however I wouldn't be able to manage the display separately on the two outputs.

Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the image path by using following code:

```
<?php
var_dump($node);
?>
```

Now find the path of the image and write the following code:

```
<?php
theme('image_style', array('style_name' => 'stylename', 'path' => 'image path', 'alt' => 'image alt', 'title' => 'image title', 'width' => 'some width', 'height' => 'some height')));
?>
```

Where you can define your own style name. I hope you know how to create image styles.
Just Goto **admin/config/media/image-styles** and add your style and use it in above code. Use above code twice to print images in two different style.

Entire code:

```
// filename relative to files directory
// e.g. 'masthead.jpg'
$filename = $node->field_image['und'][0]['filename'];

// relative path to raw image in 'scheme' format
// e.g. 'public://masthead.jpg'
$image_uri = file_build_uri($filename);

// relative path to 'styled' image (using an arbitrary 'banner' style) in 'scheme' format
// e.g. 'public://styles/banner/public/masthead.jpg'
image_style_path('banner', $filename);


// html for a styled image
// e.g. '<img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://mysite.com/sites/default/files/styles/banner/public/masthead.jpg" alt="" />'
print  theme('image_style', array('style_name' => 'banner', 'path' => $image_uri));
```

Comment: I forgot to mention each node will have multiple images in the image field. If I add this code to my node.tpl.php file, will: "$filename = $node->field_image['und'][0]['filename']" get all the individual images in the image field and output a value for each or do I need to put it inside some sort of foreach loop?

Comment: @InfluenceJamie: You can create a separate tpl for each node type like node--nodetype.tpl.php

Comment: Yeah, that's not what I was asking, I know that I can have a separate template like node--news_articles.tpl.php and node--blog_posts.tpl.php.

What I'm asking is, I will have multiple images in a single node as in the node type might be houses, and for each house there are multiple images in the image field. Do I need to put the above statements into a foreach loop in order to have each image printed twice with the desired image cache?

Comment: I think in that case you have to use foreach() loop only. And display print both the image cache or which ever you want

Comment: I'm having trouble wrapping this statement in a foreach loop. If I use your code as is, it outputs the first image in my image field. However, if I try and wrap the statement in a foreach loop in order to output every image in the image_field I get an error. Any ideas on how the statement could be best wrapped in a foreach loop in order to achieve what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Please show you code..let's fix it